# Concurrent network I/O

Tags: architecture, concurrency, networking

Correct me if I am wrong, but regarding file I/O and concurrency, I understand that it makes no sense to read 2 files concurrently, since the data bus cannot be used simultaneously. This means that trying to read 2 files concurrently will, at best, have the same performance as sequential reading, and worst on average, since the device controller will have to keep switching blocks to read the files.

Does this apply to network I/O? Does it makes sense to have 1 thread per connection (or to be more correct, a thread pool managing a list of connections) where threads try to read from different connections at the same time?

I suppose the network device have the same limitations as the storage device, and would make more sense to have a thread that reads from connections continuously (skipping those that does not have any available data on each pass), and then process the read data of each connection concurrently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It depends whether you are expecting the network to go as fast as it can, or whether you're expecting to wait most of the time.

If you are downloading a large file as fast as your network can handle it, you might not gain anything from parallel downloads, because downloading 2 files at once will just make each one half as fast. Note that the "switching overhead" for networks is low; there is no seek time.

However, if you are waiting for events most of the time, then it makes sense to wait for them concurrently. If you are only receiving a trickle of data, then you can receive two trickles in the same amount of time as one trickle. You should aim to receive as many trickles at the same time as possible. This is common when you are writing a server which waits for requests. This is also true if you are downloading a large file but the download is slower than your network can handle.

Note that "concurrent waiting" doesn't mean multiple threads; if you have a large number of "trickle" connections, it is generally more efficient to wait for many sockets *on the same thread* using something like `epoll`. This varies depends on your platform though: in Linux C, you would use `epoll`; in Windows C, you would use overlapped I/O; in Go, you would use goroutines (which translate to one of the above); in C#, you would use async/await (which translates to one of the above); ...

Comment: The connections send and receive small packets, so I guess it makes sense to wait for them concurrently. Thanks a lot!.

Comment: For real life networks, single TCP connection isn't usually the way to maximize throughput. Look up "long fat network" for more details.

Answer (score 2):

You are sort-of right, however networking should not be done with a thread/connection. It doesn't scale and it's not the optimum design.

Most all languages with I/O have a non-blocking variant of networking. This does not allocate a thread/connection, rather only uses a thread from a pool from every incoming/outgoing packet. This means you are notified when data is available, instead of you using a full (heavy-weight) thread to continuously poll.

What you should be doing is processing the packet as fast as possible when you're notified, so that the network stack at the OS level can read the next packet when it arrives. Failing to do this might trigger back-pressure on the TCP/IP level and cause your download to slow down.

Another interesting topic if you are downloading "files" as fast as possible is "[zero-copy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero-copy)" operation. This means that you can actually redirect incoming data straight to other "files" (actual files or other network connections) *without involving the CPU*. You can't really go any faster than that, if you can do it in your environment.

Comment: > "a thread from a pool from every incoming/outgoing packet"
I guess you are refering to asynchronous I/O?

Comment: Yes, or "non-blocking" I/O, i.e. it does not block any threads.

Comment: "networking should not be done with a thread/connection" – That depends on the platform. On BEAM, for example, a thread (actually a process) only weighs ~300 bytes and you can easily have tens of millions of them. There is no reason to use any complex async I/O schemes or thread pools or anything like that. Just fire up a process per connection.